# How to compare and set exact collection in java and drools?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, drools

I have a java class as below

```
public  class Ball 
{
  private int size;
  private String brand;
  private ArrayList<String> colour;
  private HashMap<String, String> price;

  //getter and setters

}
```

I want to create Drools rule (java dialect) to read the size, brand and colour and set price map accordingly.

colour ArrayList should match exact e.g. if a ball **has Red, Black & Blue** colour together, then a particular rule should apply.

price map e.g. **[{"US", "1.79"},{"UK", "1.48"},{"UAE", "11.37"}]**. Don't confuse this with json, it is a java HashMap.

```
rule "rule 1"
when
ball : Ball
(
 size == 14,
 brand ==  "NIVIA",
 colour ==  //here i want to compare exact match of the arraylist.
)
then
 ball.setPrice(//here i want to set price map);
end
```

Please help to create the .drl file

Comment: @Taegost : There is no question of what i have tried, i donot know how to use collections in rule file. I am asking this question when i **tried** to find solution on web but could not find any condition similar as mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we should question the use of a `List<String>` for holding a number of colours. Is order really important? It's possible that you want to distinguish a red ball with green and blue dots from a white ball with purple stripes, but even so "order" alone won't be able to express all subtleties. Point is, `List.equals` (and also `==` in Drools) is defined to return true if and only if elements are equal, *one by one*.

The same problem arises if you use a `String[]` and call `Arrays.equals()`.

I think the best solution would be to use a

```
private Set<String> colour;
```

and write the rule as

```
rule "rule 1"
when
    ball: Ball( size == 14, brand ==  "NIVIA",
                colour == new HashSet( Arrays.asList("Red", "Black", "Blue") ) )
then
    ball.setPrice(...);
end
```

Your Java application might provide a Ball method:

```
public boolean hasColours( String... colours )
```

which would simplify the notation in the rule:

```
  ball: Ball( size == 14, brand ==  "NIVIA",
              ball.hasColours("Red", "Black", "Blue") )
```

Comment: I am sorry I did not get it, does the drl file understands HashSet (java collection API) also? Apologies, I am new to drools, but I will be surprised, if drools can handle it, then life is gonna be really simple for me (for now)

Comment: Between 'then' and 'end' you can write extended Java code; possibly a few restrictions still apply (since I was using it a few years ago).